# Can we do bean injection to Pig UDF

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-pig, pig-udf

I am using Spring Boot in my project that runs a Pig script. I have defined a Pig UDF. I wonder whether I can inject a bean into this UDF class. The UDF class is something like this:
The UDF that works now looks like this:

```
public class MyUDF extends EvalFunc<String> {
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        final ClassA instanceA = new ClassA();
        return instanceA.func(input);
    }
}
```

I wonder whether I can leave the instantiation of `instanceA` to spring container? I tried

```
public class MyUDF extends EvalFunc<String> {

    @Autowired
    private final ClassA instanceA;

    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        return instanceA.func(input);
    }
}
```

and also defined a constructor, but neither of these two methods works. Is it because this `instanceA` should be static?

Is there a way to use Bean factory in Pig UDF?

Comment: What annotation do you have on `ClassA`? Can you show us the definition of  `ClassA`?

Comment: When I tried it myself, I created a configuration class
```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public ClassA instanceA {
        return new ClassA();
    }
}
```